# R: Repeating elements of a list for usage in purrr::pmap()

Tags: r, nested-lists, purrr

This is just a "cosmetical" thing, but I just can't get it to work. :(

I have a nested list that I want to pass to `pmap()`. Some elements are repeated within the sublists. I'm looking for an elegant way to repeat elements multiple times within a sublist.

Simplified example with less elements:

```
arg_list <- list(url = x,
                 category = c("/activity",
                              "/current",
                              "/desktop",
                              "/login/user",
                              "/message",
                              "/forum"),
                 action = list(c("ACTIVITY_RESUME", "ACTIVITY_PAUSE"),
                               c("FRAGMENT_RESUME", "FRAGMENT_PAUSE"),
                               c("FRAGMENT_RESUME", "FRAGMENT_PAUSE"),
                               c("onResume", "onPause"),
                               c("onResume", "onPause"),
                               c("onResume", "onPause"))


get_durations <- function(x, category, action) { ... }   


durations <- pmap(.l = arg_list, safely(get_durations))
```

For example, I want to repeat `c("onResume", "onPause")` three times, instead of typing it by hand.

I tried various variations of `rep(list(c("onResume", "onPause")), times = 3)` but I wasn't able to extract the elements as neccessary.

Thank you! :)

Comment: What are the use of `safely` and `get_durations`? and how are they relevant to the question?

Comment: These functions are not relevant to the question. I'm sorry! I just wanted to provide an example that is close to my actual code.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

`rep(list(c("onResume", "onPause")), times = 3)` should work. What seems to be issue?

If you need to repeat different vectors a different number of times, you can use `map2` (Note the usage of `flatten` to convert the final list-of-lists to a list of vectors):

```
map2( list(c("ACTIVITY_RESUME", "ACTIVITY_PAUSE"),
           c("FRAGMENT_RESUME", "FRAGMENT_PAUSE"),
           c("onResume", "onPause")), 
      1:3, ~rep(list(.x), .y) ) %>% purrr::flatten()
# [[1]]
# [1] "ACTIVITY_RESUME" "ACTIVITY_PAUSE" 
#
# [[2]]
# [1] "FRAGMENT_RESUME" "FRAGMENT_PAUSE" 
#
# [[3]]
# [1] "FRAGMENT_RESUME" "FRAGMENT_PAUSE"
#
# [[4]]
# [1] "onResume" "onPause"
#
# [[5]]
# [1] "onResume" "onPause" 
#
# [[6]]
# [1] "onResume" "onPause"
```

Comment: The problem with `rep(list(c("onResume", "onPause")), times = 3)` appears to be that it produces another list nested inside the `action` list and I couldn't come up with a way to extract the character vectors as neccessary. But your solution with map_2 is very nice and solves it. Thank you very much! Just one thing: Without parentheses `purrr::flatten()` throws an error in my code. Is your `flatten` from another package? :D

Comment: Sorry, I should have been more explicit. My example uses `purrr::flatten()`. I tend to omit parentheses in simple examples, but it's a good idea to write `%>% flatten()` or even `%>% purrr::flatten()` in complex expressions.